# Unable to Find the NinjectWebCommon.cs File in App_Start folder

Tags: ninject, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple Query, I was following a tutorial that was about MVC5 Project.
I have added EntityFrameWork 6.1.3 ,Ninject and Moq from Manage Nuget packages in my project but i didn't find NinjectWebCommon.cs Class in my Project's App_Start folder.
Now how i can resolved this Issue?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348311/ninject-mvc5-not-generating-ninjectwebcommon-cs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348311/ninject-mvc5-not-generating-ninjectwebcommon-cs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [Ninject.MVC5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/) package from Nuget. This will create the NinjectWebCommon.cs class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348311/ninject-mvc5-not-generating-ninjectwebcommon-cs